# How to play stream with rtsp on wowza?

Tags: rtsp, live-streaming, wowza

I execure command ffmpeg to stream one file mp4 ( h264 or h265) follow: (RTSP Sources : Open (no authentication required))

ffmpeg -re -i inputvideo.mp4 -strict -2 -f rtsp rtsp://35.163.219.12:1935/live/myStream.sdp

I played on wowza streaming enginemanager with test player. 
MPEG DASH: [url]http://ip:1935/live/myStream/manifest.mpd[/url]
Adobe RTMP:
server : rtmp://ip:1935/live ; stream : myStream
or 
server : rtmp://ip:1935/live ; stream : myStream.sdp
or 
server : rtsp://ip:1935/live ; stream : myStream
or 
server : rtsp://ip:1935/live ; stream : myStream.sdp
Adobe HDS:
[url]http://ip:1935/live/myStream/manifest.f4m[/url]

Then, i play on vlc with rtsp://35.163.219.12:1935/live/myStream.sdp, but not open

Howerver, all cann't run. 
How to play it? Or have error?
Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you don't have source authentication enabled for RTSP as
   you are not passing any user credentials. These are enabled by
   default on a Wowza application. Go into Source Security in your
   application configuration and set RTSP to open.
2. Check that the stream is coming in correctly by going into the
   Incoming Streams page of your live application. If you click on the
   incoming stream, it should be showing an inbound data of what you
   would expect your stream's bitrate would be.
3. Your player will need to support the playback format that you are
   using.

Comment: thanks you very much. I run command: 
ffmpeg -re -i sample.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -r 24 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -sc_threshold 0 -vb 310k -c:a libvo_aacenc -ab 40k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -f rtsp -muxdelay 0.1 rtsp://username:password@[wowza-ip-address]:1935/live/myStre‌​am
It is oke.